# Keycloak browser flow: enable user change if already authentified

Tags: authentication, keycloak

Is it possible with Keycloak on the login page, for an already authentified user, **to ask him to confirm the user or to let him change user**?

I mean, like Google can do for the same scenario, when using it a third party authentication? Or something like this?

I'd like my users to be aware of the Keycloak user they're using during login.
Currently, when going to the login page in browser flow: if the user is already authentified, we don't see the login page and are **immediately redirected** to the desired page.